# Integration Testing FubuMVC

Tags: fubumvc

I was looking at this example https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubumvc/blob/master/src/FubuMVC.AspNetTesting/Http/can_read_response.cs and wondering how I can integration test fubu mvc.

What I want to do is give it my request or input model, and then all the behaviours and handlers executed, so I am given back just the view model or redirect i.e. I don't need it to render the view.

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the tests in the integration testing project in FubuMVC instead.  If you can get away with it, it's *much* easier to use the Self Host capability instead.  I suppose this could be my weekly blog post for the week.

Comment: I've found it much easier to test the behaviors and actions in isolation. Then test your conventions to make sure your chains are getting setup correctly.

After that's all said and done, spin up SelfHost to hit your chain end-to-end. There's nothing stopping you from configuring the container before hitting it in SelfHost either if you wanted to stub some services (e.g., email/sms gateway, service bus)

Comment: thanks for the replies. I've tested my behaviours and handlers separately already. But I got nervous about end-to-end interactions - particularly between validation and happy-path tests

Comment: My next suggestion would be: Come to CodeMash and watch us show off StoryTeller + FubuMVC + Serenity ;)